# Extracting Portion of Url using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, google-maps

I have this URL

> https://www.google.com/maps/place/Aleem+Iqbal+SEO/@31.888433,73.263572,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x39221cb7e4154211:0x9cf2bb941cace556!8m2!3d31.888433!4d73.2657607

I am trying to Extract 31.888433,73.263572 from the URL
and send 31.888433 to TextBox 1
and 73.263572 to TextBox 2

Can you give me an example how can i do this with regex or anything else

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.split(). This method takes an array of chars which are the discriminants for the splitting. The better solution is to split by '/', take the string that starts with '@' and then split it by ','. You'll have an array with two string: first latitude, second longitude.
 Should be immediate using LINQ

Comment: Can you please give an example

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is in the code comments.

```
    Dim strURL As String = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Aleem+Iqbal+SEO/@31.888433,73.263572,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x39221cb7e4154211:0x9cf2bb941cace556!8m2!3d31.888433!4d73.2657607"
    'Find the index of the first occurance of the @ character
    Dim index As Integer = strURL.IndexOf("@")
    'Get the string from that the next character to the end of the string
    Dim firstSubstring As String = strURL.Substring(index + 1)      
    'Get a Char array of the separators
    Dim separators As Char() = {CChar(",")}
    'Split the string into an array based on the separator; the separator is not part of the array
    Dim strArray As String() = firstSubstring.Split(separators)
    'The first and second elements of the array is what you want
    Dim strTextBox1 As String = strArray(0)
    Dim strTextBox2 As String = strArray(1)
    Debug.Print($"{strTextBox1} For TextBox1 and {strTextBox2} for TextBox2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally Made a working Code Myself

> Private _reg As Regex = New
>   Regex("@(-?[\d]*.[\d]*),(-?[\d]*.[\d]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
>       Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
>           Dim url As String = WebBrowser2.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString()

```
    ' The input string.
    Dim value As String = WebBrowser2.Url.ToString
    Dim myString As String = WebBrowser2.Url.ToString

    Dim regex1 = New Regex("@(-?\d+\.\d+)")
    Dim regex2 = New Regex(",(-?\d+\.\d+)")
    Dim match = regex1.Match(myString)
    Dim match2 = regex2.Match(myString)

    If match.Success Then
        Dim match3 As String = match.Value.Replace("@", "")
        Dim match4 As String = match2.Value.Replace(",", "")
        Label1.Text = match3
        Label2.Text = match4
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim url As String = "www.google.com/maps/place/Aleem+Iqbal+SEO/@31.888433,73.263572,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x39221cb7e4154211:0x9cf2bb941cace556!8m2!3d31.888433!4d73.2657607"
        Dim temp As String = Regex.Match(url, "@.*,").Value.Replace("@", "")
        Dim arrTemp As String() = temp.Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        Label1.Text = arrTemp(0)
        Label2.Text = arrTemp(1)
```